# Why do we represent each column by x and y values in column picture of a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I started watching Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra lectures. In the first lecture, he has the following system of linear equations

$$\begin{cases}
 2x - y = 0 \\
 -x + 2y = 3 
\end{cases}
$$

When he talks about column picture of the equations, he writes the equations as the following linear combination of columns

$X\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$ + $Y\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$

And then, he shows how it looks geometrically as follows
[image: Column picture]

One thing that i don't understand from the above representation is, how can we consider two coefficients of X (2 and -1) and plot them as if they are X and Y coordinates of a vector?

Comment: I've never seen such a representation before ... I mean, of course you can just plot the points on a plane, but I don't understand what we gain from this.

Comment: From what i have understand, i think column representation shows that any point is a linear transformation of basis vectors? idk, i thought of this based on 3blue1brown videos

Comment: @MattiP., somehow, i feel this has to do with the isomorphism . like, in a way.. these coefficients  and 2d coordinate system are isomorpic . does this make any sense?

Comment: It took this in the following sense: _we can_ represent things that way. It's something you find out, the same way ppl didn't represent planes before Decart. If you do it, you get all the same conclusions, and it's way more powerful.

Comment: The two coefficients of X or Y are just a set of two numbers. It just happens to fit the definition of a vector and therefore we can think of them as vectors. Vectors are not represented as coordinates. They have a direction and a magnitude. The vector (2,-1) can be represented at many different points on the same plane (your representation just shows the one originating from the point (0,0). So, don't think of vector as coordinates, but a quantity having a length and a direction. But that is just a geometric representation of what essentially is a an abstract idea of a set of two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We didn't represent X,Y tables of data in X,Y plots before 1600.

It was a sort of discovery, and you can test it, predict, and so on.

It is useful.

In the same way, you can look at those coefficients as being vectors, and it's very insightful. Because from their shape and values, you can derive properties of solutions etc.

It is exactly the same with matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following substitutions: $u=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$, $v=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$. Then, Gilbert Strang  says that we have to add some amount (say $x=a$) of the vector  $u$ to some amount (say $y=b$) of the vector $v$ to get the vector $w=au+bv$. Next, he finds the right amounts to make the equality true and simply draws them. I don't think there is something perplexing :)

Comment: But, my question was.. how can we just consider coefficients as X as x and y coordinates? is there a reason for that?